# FileUpload Validator error message always shown .net

Tags: asp.net, .net, regex, file-upload

I have a problem with my code:

```
<asp:FileUpload ID="fulBrowse" runat="server" />
<asp:Button ID="btnLoad" runat="server" Text="Load" OnClick="btnLoad_Click" />
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="fulBrowseValidator"
                                runat="server"
                                ErrorMessage="Upload Zip or Dxf files only"
                                ValidationExpression="^(([a-zA-Z]:)|(\\{2}\w+)\$?)(\\(\w[\w].*))(.zip|.ZIP|.dxf|.DXF)$"
                                ControlToValidate="fulBrowse">
</asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
```

that is, even if the file uploaded is a ZIP or a DXF, when my function `btnLoad_Click` ends, the `ErrorMessage` is shown, .

Here is the result:

[image: my_result]**

Does anyone know why?

Thank you

**Upload succesful is a label which is set when `btnLoad_Click` ends.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would change the validator to simply `^.+[\.zip|\.ZIP|\.dxf|\.DXF]$` since the file uploader will validate the filename for you (unless you're looking for a specific filename).  You can expand on the `zip/dfx` case matching via `\.zIp|\.ZIp|...` or you can

Disable client side scripting with `EnableClientScript="False"` and add the

Case insensitive flag `(?i:^.+[\.zip|\.dxf]$)`

Comment: Hi, I tried your solution and it doesn't give me the error message when i load a zip or a dxf file. Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove the `^(([a-zA-Z]:)|(\\{2}\w+)\$?)(\\(\w[\w].*))` if the file name contains numbers it will show error too,so try to make it like my example below

```
      <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="revImage" ControlToValidate="fulBrowse" 
            ValidationExpression="^.*\.((.zip|.ZIP|.dxf|.DXF))$" 
            ErrorMessage="Upload Zip or Dxf files only"
            Text="" runat="server" />
```

Comment: I tried your solution but i got the error message both with zip and dfx files